# JQuery Scrollbar not working

Tags: jquery, css, scrollbar

I am trying to put a scrollbar in the text area on one of my projects. After a little research I decided to use the Gromo's jQuery Scrollbar

http://gromo.github.io/jquery.scrollbar/

So I loaded everything up on the head (jQuery, The Js for this plugin, and the JavaScript on the demo page).

Instead of loading the scrollbar it simply just does away with any scrollbar, to include the default one.

Here's the code I'm trying:

HTML:

```
<textarea class="textarea-scrollbar scrollbar-outer">
Lorem ipsum...
</textarea>
```

CSS:

```
/*************** SCROLLBAR BASE CSS ***************/

.scroll-wrapper {
    overflow: hidden !important;
    padding: 0 !important;
    position: relative;
}

.scroll-wrapper > .scroll-content {
    border: none !important;
    box-sizing: content-box !important;
    height: auto;
    left: 0;
    margin: 0;
    max-height: none;
    max-width: none !important;
    overflow: scroll !important;
    padding: 0;
    position: relative !important;
    top: 0;
    width: auto !important;
}

.scroll-wrapper > .scroll-content::-webkit-scrollbar {
    height: 0;
    width: 0;
}

.scroll-element {
    display: none;
}
.scroll-element, .scroll-element div {
    box-sizing: content-box;
}

.scroll-element.scroll-x.scroll-scrollx_visible,
.scroll-element.scroll-y.scroll-scrolly_visible {
    display: block;
}

.scroll-element .scroll-bar,
.scroll-element .scroll-arrow {
    cursor: default;
}

.scroll-textarea {
    border: 1px solid #cccccc;
    border-top-color: #999999;
}
.scroll-textarea > .scroll-content {
    overflow: hidden !important;
}
.scroll-textarea > .scroll-content > textarea {
    border: none !important;
    box-sizing: border-box;
    height: 100% !important;
    margin: 0;
    max-height: none !important;
    max-width: none !important;
    overflow: scroll !important;
    outline: none;
    padding: 2px;
    position: relative !important;
    top: 0;
    width: 100% !important;
}
.scroll-textarea > .scroll-content > textarea::-webkit-scrollbar {
    height: 0;
    width: 0;
}




/*************** TEXTAREA STYLES ***************/

.textarea-scrollbar {
    height: 250px;
    width: 500px;
}
```

JavaScript:

jQuery 1.7.2, Gromo's Plugin js: http://gromo.github.io/jquery.scrollbar/jquery.scrollbar.js and...

```
jQuery(document).ready(function(){
    jQuery('.textarea-scrollbar').scrollbar();
});
```

Here's my fiddle: http://jsfiddle.net/qLobcjd0/1/

Here's the demo page with a working textarea scrollbar: http://gromo.github.io/jquery.scrollbar/demo/basic.html

Any assistance is appreciated, thank you!

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I have updated your example: http://jsfiddle.net/qLobcjd0/3/

I have removed all styles except:

```
.textarea-scrollbar {
    height: 250px;
    width: 500px;
}
```

and added reference to [jquery.scrollbar.css](https://github.com/gromo/jquery.scrollbar/blob/master/jquery.scrollbar.css)

Answer (score 2):

I believe just just lost some css for simple outer scrollbar. Check this out: [working example](http://jsfiddle.net/qLobcjd0/2/)

CSS code:

```
/*************** SCROLLBAR BASE CSS ***************/

.scroll-wrapper {
    overflow: hidden !important;
    padding: 0 !important;
    position: relative;
}

.scroll-wrapper > .scroll-content {
    border: none !important;
    box-sizing: content-box !important;
    height: auto;
    left: 0;
    margin: 0;
    max-height: none;
    max-width: none !important;
    overflow: scroll !important;
    padding: 0;
    position: relative !important;
    top: 0;
    width: auto !important;
}

.scroll-wrapper > .scroll-content::-webkit-scrollbar {
    height: 0;
    width: 0;
}

.scroll-element {
    display: none;
}
.scroll-element, .scroll-element div {
    box-sizing: content-box;
}

.scroll-element.scroll-x.scroll-scrollx_visible,
.scroll-element.scroll-y.scroll-scrolly_visible {
    display: block;
}

.scroll-element .scroll-bar,
.scroll-element .scroll-arrow {
    cursor: default;
}

.scroll-textarea {
    border: 1px solid #cccccc;
    border-top-color: #999999;
}
.scroll-textarea > .scroll-content {
    overflow: hidden !important;
}
.scroll-textarea > .scroll-content > textarea {
    border: none !important;
    box-sizing: border-box;
    height: 100% !important;
    margin: 0;
    max-height: none !important;
    max-width: none !important;
    overflow: scroll !important;
    outline: none;
    padding: 2px;
    position: relative !important;
    top: 0;
    width: 100% !important;
}
.scroll-textarea > .scroll-content > textarea::-webkit-scrollbar {
    height: 0;
    width: 0;
}




/*************** SIMPLE OUTER SCROLLBAR ***************/

.scrollbar-outer > .scroll-element,
.scrollbar-outer > .scroll-element div
{
    border: none;
    margin: 0;
    padding: 0;
    position: absolute;
    z-index: 10;
}

.scrollbar-outer > .scroll-element {
    background-color: #ffffff;
}

.scrollbar-outer > .scroll-element div {
    display: block;
    height: 100%;
    left: 0;
    top: 0;
    width: 100%;
}

.scrollbar-outer > .scroll-element.scroll-x {
    bottom: 0;
    height: 12px;
    left: 0;
    width: 100%;
}

.scrollbar-outer > .scroll-element.scroll-y {
    height: 100%;
    right: 0;
    top: 0;
    width: 12px;
}

.scrollbar-outer > .scroll-element.scroll-x .scroll-element_outer { height: 8px; top: 2px; }
.scrollbar-outer > .scroll-element.scroll-y .scroll-element_outer { left: 2px; width: 8px; }

.scrollbar-outer > .scroll-element .scroll-element_outer { overflow: hidden; }
.scrollbar-outer > .scroll-element .scroll-element_track { background-color: #eeeeee; }

.scrollbar-outer > .scroll-element .scroll-element_outer,
.scrollbar-outer > .scroll-element .scroll-element_track,
.scrollbar-outer > .scroll-element .scroll-bar {
    -webkit-border-radius: 8px;
    -moz-border-radius: 8px;
    border-radius: 8px;
}

.scrollbar-outer > .scroll-element .scroll-bar { background-color: #d9d9d9; }
.scrollbar-outer > .scroll-element .scroll-bar:hover { background-color: #c2c2c2; }
.scrollbar-outer > .scroll-element.scroll-draggable .scroll-bar { background-color: #919191; }


/* scrollbar height/width & offset from container borders */

.scrollbar-outer > .scroll-content.scroll-scrolly_visible { left: -12px; margin-left: 12px; }
.scrollbar-outer > .scroll-content.scroll-scrollx_visible { top:  -12px; margin-top:  12px; }

.scrollbar-outer > .scroll-element.scroll-x .scroll-bar { min-width: 10px; }
.scrollbar-outer > .scroll-element.scroll-y .scroll-bar { min-height: 10px; }


/* update scrollbar offset if both scrolls are visible */

.scrollbar-outer > .scroll-element.scroll-x.scroll-scrolly_visible .scroll-element_track { left: -14px; }
.scrollbar-outer > .scroll-element.scroll-y.scroll-scrollx_visible .scroll-element_track { top: -14px; }

.scrollbar-outer > .scroll-element.scroll-x.scroll-scrolly_visible .scroll-element_size { left: -14px; }
.scrollbar-outer > .scroll-element.scroll-y.scroll-scrollx_visible .scroll-element_size { top: -14px; }


/*************** TEXTAREA STYLES ***************/

.textarea-scrollbar {
    height: 250px;
    width: 500px;
}
```

Or just add "textarea-scrollbar scrollbar-outer" class if you have jquery.scrollbar.css.